# AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-osx Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon

Tags: react-native, gradle, proguard, aapt, aapt2

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-osx Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

while running =>npx react-native run-android get this error
//android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8')
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
       
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem, and had a very similar `classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")` line in my build.gradle. I discovered [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76842598/app-crashing-on-android-12-after-updating-to-sdk-34) which was using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'`, which surprised me because the IDE only suggested up to version 4.2.2. I updated my AGP plugin to 7.3.1 (the latest my IDE version supported), and the app built just fine! Maybe that will help you with this inscrutable error.

Comment: I removed react-native-track-player from my project and it worked for me.